# Protractor typescript issue with Boolean true in if statement

Tags: typescript, protractor

I want if an element is not selected then only i should select it ,here I am using if else in typescript but it does't work for me

```
let inputEle = element(by.xpath('//div[@class="pq-select-menu"]//span[text()="Users(1003)"]/preceding-sibling::input'));
console.log(await inputEle.isSelected()); //true or false
let val=inputEle.isSelected();

if (val== true){
    console.log('Is Already selected');
}else{
    await element(by.xpath('//*[@id="quincbody"]/*//div[contains(@class, "pq-select-menu")]//*[contains(text(),"Users(1003)")]')).click();
}
```

Comment: You need to add a await `inputEle.isSelected()` as it is a promise (along with any other command which interacts with the browser) and you should also probably be using `===` instead of `==` for boolean comparisons

Comment: Thanks @DublinDev for valuable information.

Answer (score 1):

Protractor deals in promises. As such, `val` will be of `Promise<boolean>`
You could try this:

```
        let inputEle = element(by.xpath('//div[@class="pq-select-menu"]//span[text()="Users(1003)"]/preceding-sibling::input'));
        inputEle.isSelected().then(selected => {
            if (selected) {
                console.log('Is Already selected');
            } else {
                await element(by.xpath('//*[@id="quincbody"]/*//div[contains(@class, "pq-select-menu")]//*[contains(text(),"Users(1003)")]')).click();
            }
            // the rest of the code if there's any.
        });
```